# Changing css based on javascript value fetch from API

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code below that returns an updated value from an API every seconds in an html span tag:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $.get('https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=XXBTZEUR', function(data){
            var kraken_btc_eur = data.result.XXBTZEUR.c[0]
            $("#kraken_btc_eur").text(kraken_btc_eur);
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

How can I change the css of the `<span id="kraken_btc_eur">` depending on whether the value of the variable `var kraken_btc_eur` changes from a prior value.

I figure I must include an IF statement, create a new variable to compare to the old update and clear the variable for this to be executed in the next second again PLUS different ID for up or down. I am not sure how to implement that.

Thanks all for your guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
$(function() {
    var kraken_btc_eur_old = 0;

    setInterval(function(){
        $.get('https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=XXBTZEUR', function(data){
            var kraken_btc_eur = data.result.XXBTZEUR.c[0];
            if (kraken_btc_eur_old != kraken_btc_eur) {
                // Change css
            }
            kraken_btc_eur_old = kraken_btc_eur;
            $("#kraken_btc_eur").text(kraken_btc_eur);
        });
    }, 1000);

});
```

Comment: Thanks i just change 'kraken_btc_eur_old != kraken_btc_eur' for 'kraken_btc_eur_old > kraken_btc_eur' with an else statement.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing current to new...

Something like:

```
if(kraken_btc_eur !== $("#kraken_btc_eur").text()) {
  // if different change background and add new text
  $("#kraken_btc_eur").css('background', 'red').text(kraken_btc_eur);
}
```

This way you only update if different, no point updating something with the same value